# StringBuilder to Array of Strings how to convert

Tags: android, arrays, string, stringbuilder

cant anything find or read about this problem ( it's problem only for me but maybe someone know way to fix  it.

i have function which reading from asset folder

```
public String[] loadFromAsset() throws IOException
    {
        String TEMPBUFFER = null;
        String[] temp;
        temp = new String[60];
        int tempc = 0;
        BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(cont.getAssets().open("myquests.txt")));
        String line="";//  = bReader.readLine();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while (line != null) {

            line = bReader.readLine();
            sb.append(line).append("TABTAB");
            tempc++;
  }
         bReader.close();
    //convert SB to array here
         saveCount(tempc-1);
         return temp;

    }
```

Need return array of strings like temp[50] = (1,2,3,4,5,...n+1)
But i can't find a way to convert from stringBuilder to array :( 
Please,maybe anyone know it. Tell me

Just need return SB as a array (like temp[])  or convert SB to Array here  like sb->convert->temp[]

Comment: why do you use the stringbuilder in the first place then?

Comment: you need to convert temp ?

Comment: need convert StringBuilder to temp(array of strings) using it cos it's fastes way

Comment: it is faster compared to what?

Comment: sb better and faster than if i will be use like : temp[tempc]=line; // dont know why - but it's take more time than if i using stringbuilder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`temp = sb.toString().split("TABTAB");` will split the string and return an array of strings for each line. But I'm not completely sure that this is what you are trying to do...

Comment: thank u . tried it too and it's work , going here but u already answered , im just write "return sb.toString().split("TABTAB");

Comment: good point. no need for the temp variable if you only want to return the result.

Answer (score 2):

To convert stringbuilder to string array do the following:

```
string sbString = sb.toString();
String[] ary = sbString.split("TABTAB");
```