# How do I convert string builder to string array in Android?

Tags: android, string, listview, stringbuilder

I have a string builder in Android which is filled with data from a database, and I want to display that data using a list view. For that I want to covert string builder into an array of strings. Can somebody help me in this conversion, or suggest to me some other technique.

Comment: you have some character to split it into array of strings ? If yes, whats that ?

Comment: post code which you have tried so far to answer your question properly.

Comment: is there delimeter character ? use it to split

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can find [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25811986/stringbuilder-to-array-of-strings-how-to-convert)

`tempArray = sb.toString().split("ABCABC");` will split the string and return an array of strings for each line.

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
String sbString = sb.ToString();
String[] ary = "abc".split("TABTAB");
```