# How do i change the stringbuilder to array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have the following code to get Text file as input from the user.I would like to change the code to read the input text file and store each line in array.I am using c# console application.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog op = new OpenFileDialog();
            op.Filter = "CBL files (*.CBL)|*.cbl";
            if (op.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                textBox1.Text = op.FileName;
                string path = op.FileName;
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
                {
                    while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
                    {
                        sb.AppendLine(sr.ReadToEnd());
                    }
                    richTextBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
```

Please help as I am new to coding.

Comment: StreamBuilder, nice neologism ;)

Comment: Use `richTextBox1.Lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path);`

Comment: It is not at all clear to me what your question is. What's wrong with your current code? What do you want it to do instead? If you want to insert the text into an array, then just do that instead of appending it to a StringBuilder object. Where is the problem?

Comment: Instead of sr.ReadToEnd try sr.ReadLine assuming you want each line added into sb?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [StringBuilder to Array of Strings how to convert](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25811986/stringbuilder-to-array-of-strings-how-to-convert)

Comment: Have you tried : `File.ReadAllLines(op.FileName)` ?

Answer (score 6):

To answer your specific question, you can do the following:

```
string[] lines = sb.ToString().Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray());
```

However, this is a lot of overkill for what it is you are actually trying to do. There is a prebuilt method for reading a file into a string array:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(op.FileName);
```

Comment: `Split` receives either a char array or a string array, so for this to work you should do something like `.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None)`.

Comment: @Andrew Technically true, but I'd argue that changing `Environment.NewLine` to `Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray()` is simpler.

Comment: I tried that too, but that has a different behavior: that will give you an extra empty string, as it will split by either `\r` or `\n` (in case NewLine includes both, like in Windows), and not when both are next to each other.

Comment: @Andrew That is true for Windows, but not for just about any other OS on the planet. For those, the above code will work fine. On windows, you can simply add `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` to the parameters of the call.

Comment: @Andrew But at any rate, this is beside the point, as that specific example was merely to answer OP's question specifically as it pertains to splitting IO input on new lines. The second half of the answer shows that that is not actually a good way to approach the situation anyway, as there is a prebuilt method to import a file's contents as a newline-broken string array. Using the first solution is reinventing the wheel, so regardless of whether or not it's actually correct code, don't do it.

Comment: I bet more than 90% of the people reading this use Windows, so they will have issues with the `ToCharArray` approach. Using `RemoveEmptyEntries` is still kind of a workaround, as it could be possible that there are actual separate `\r` or `\n` characters and the user doesn't want to split there. ;) Finally, the subject only talks about splitting a `StringArray`, and that's what brought me here, so another user may check the answer without reading the question details. :)

Comment: @Andrew There are other more visible questions on SO that more adequately answer the specific question of converting a `StringBuilder` to a string array. This question is the result of its OP having an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/), so I'm not going to put a ton of time and energy into making sure the solution for Y is absolutely perfect when the primary concern of the answer is to focus on the solution for X.